# Screen flickers when running on Android 4.2. (Activity gets restarted continuously)

Tags: android, android-activity, right-to-left, android-configchanges

Some users reported that my app screen sometimes flickers when running on Android 4.2 (only!)

I tried on my device, and after putting logs, the activity is restarted and restarted again, about 3 times a second.

So what I did is to trace the method calls when it restarts continually, and here is the result:

[image: method trace output]

It seems that the problem lies in the ViewGroup.resetRtlProperties(), since this is new in Android 4.2 (17).

I can't confirm yet if this is a bug, but is there anyone else experiencing this or have any workarounds?

Comment: This might be a silly question, but how do I open this window with CPU usage stats by methods?

Comment: This is TraceView. http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and it was caused by a combination of the following two:

- An activity in landscape orientation (while the device preferred portrait)
- Code in onConfigurationChanged() of the Application subclass that changed the locale of the newConfig parameter

Instead of changing newConfig you can clone that object and change/use the clone:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    Configuration configClone = new Configuration(newConfig);
    // Change/use configClone here
    ...
}
```

Comment: it works, just one question, if i were to change the Configuration in other place beside 'onConfigurationChanged', do i still need to clone?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, adding `layoutDirection` to the list of `android:configChanges` of your `<activity>` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` fixed this problem.

Comment: how did you find this issue?