# Android flickering screen in 4.2 with no apparent reason

Tags: android, screen, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm developing an application for android and when everything should be finished I've found an extrange behaviour. In some devices the screen starts to flicker, and there is no apparent reason for that. It may happen in initial splash with only an AsyncTask quering a webservice or in the home screen with no asynctask at all.

It's strange because only happens in devices with android 4.2, nor in 2.3 or 2.2. I've tried enabling the tag harware-accelration in manifest but I've no clue for what can be the reason

Some help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could it be that you have strict mode enabled in Settings>Developer options under "Monitoring" section in your device?. This makes the screen flash when apps do long operations on main thread

Comment: no, I've checked it and that option is unchecked. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've managed how to avoid this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448108/screen-flickers-when-running-on-android-4-2-activity-gets-restarted-continuous) was the trick, just changing my Application's Override OnConfigurationChanged.
This was my old code

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {       
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Locale l = getLocale();
        Configuration config = new Configuration(newConfig); // get Modifiable Config from actual config changed
        config.locale = l;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    }
```

and I've changed to this

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {       
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Locale l = getLocale();         
        Configuration config = new Configuration(newConfig); // get Modifiable Config from actual config changed
        config.locale = l;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    }
```

I hope someone finds this useful.

Comment: It seems there is no difference between the two code blocks!

Comment: Although both blocks are the same but your trick: creating new config from the old one works.